# Read exception at method exit using ASM

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am writing a little java tool that records all method entries and exits using ASM 5.2. Below is the program which is working well. This program basically uses a try and finally (without catch) block. onMethodEnter() it records method entry. As entire mothod is put insisde try/finally, in finally block it records method exit.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class SGMethodAdapter extends AdviceAdapter {

    private String entry;
    private String exit;
    private Label startFinally = new Label();

    public SGMethodAdapter(int api, MethodVisitor mv, int access, String name, String desc, String className) {
        super(api, mv, access, name, desc);
        entry = ">" + className + ";" + name;
        exit = "<" + className + ";" + name;
    }

    public void visitCode() {
        super.visitCode();
        mv.visitLabel(startFinally);
    }

    public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
        Label endFinally = new Label();
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, null);
        mv.visitLabel(endFinally);
        onFinally(ATHROW);
        mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
        mv.visitMaxs(maxStack, maxLocals);
    }

    private void onFinally(int opcode) {
        try {
            mv.visitLdcInsn(exit);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/test/MethodEntryExitRecorder", "methodExit",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onMethodEnter() {
        try {
            super.visitLdcInsn(entry);
            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/test/MethodEntryExitRecorder", "methodEntry",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
        if (opcode != ATHROW) {
            onFinally(opcode);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want this program also to read exceptions (just read, not catch) thrown by any method before exiting. If no exception is thrown, I just want this to record normal method exit. In case an exception is thrown by a method, JVM guarantees that the exception object is available at the top of the stack at the time of method exiting. Below is the same above program I tweaked to add this behavior. Problem is, this is reading only few exceptions but not all. Unable to understand what exceptions are read and what are not read. Not sure where is the bug in the code... Any help is greatly appreciated...

```
private void onFinally(int opcode) {
    if(opcode == ATHROW) {
        try {
            mv.visitInsn(DUP);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(exit);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/test/MethodEntryExitRecorder", "methodExitWithException",
                    "(Ljava/lang/Throwable;Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            mv.visitLdcInsn(exit);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/test/MethodEntryExitRecorder", "methodExit",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected void onMethodEnter() {
    try {
        super.visitLdcInsn(entry);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/test/MethodEntryExitRecorder", "methodEntry",
                "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
    onFinally(opcode);
}
```

### **UPDATE : Better explanation of the problem**

Looks like I was not clear in my explanation of the problem.

Here it is.

1) I am developing a java tool that records all java method entries and exits (basically generates a dynamic call graph at application runtime)

2) For this I don't want to change application code. This tool should work without changing application behavior

3) To achieve this I am doing byte code instrumentation using ASM

4) This tool need to inject byte code into every method of the java application at method body starting and ending

5) Because there can be multiple exit/return points in a method, injecting recording code at method body ending is not enough because if the method returns half way through the body, method exit will not be recorded

6) To overcome that problem, I put entire application method body in try/finally (using instrumentation) without catch (because application need to catch exception, not this tool)

7) Above first program is ASM's AdviceAdapter that will inject byte code into all methods of the application at class loading time

8) onMethodEnter() will inject recording code that will record application's method as entered when invoked at runtime

9) onMethodExit() will inject recording code in the newly injected finally block to record application's method as exited at runtime (being in finally makes sure that this block of code is always executed)

Upto this is working well. It is correctly generating dynamic call graphs.

Now to this first program above I want to inject additional code that will also read exception (type and stacktrace) being thrown by the application/method. Again only reading not catching. 
Fot this I added this additional code in second program above. The problem is that this second program is reading only few exceptions but not all. Not sure where is the bug in the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Srinivas

Comment: ASM -> assembly

Comment: This question requires some level understanding of java's instruction set and opcodes like DUP, ATHROW, INVOKESTATIC, SWAP, ASTORE etc., hence I tagged assembly also. If it doesn't sound right, I will remove it.

Comment: First of all, you should stop your habit of wrapping all your code in `try { … } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }`. Proceeding with an application, when you already know that something went wrong (and hence, the generated code will be broken), makes no sense. And it clutters your code, making it hard to read. Besides, do you have an example code, whose instrumented version does throw an exception that doesn’t get handled?

Comment: @Holger provided better explanation of the problem in the update

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but what you’ve explained, has been understood. What I asked for, was some example code of the “*when I instrument the following method, exceptions of type xyz/ thrown at code location xyz are not reported*” kind.

Comment: @Holger Hmm... got you. I tried to understand that behavior but couldn't. Will try again and see if I find any clues.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement mirrors mine requirement & i am using the below code which records the exception thrown by the particular java method - It records the exception(s) only when these not catched by using try...catch...block.

```
package com.abc.agent.adapter;

import java.util.Map;
import com.abc.tm.Constants;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Type;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class PojoMethodAdviceAdapter extends AdviceAdapter  {

private String methodName;
private String className;
private String description;
private int okFlag =  newLocal(Type.BOOLEAN_TYPE); 

Label startFinally = new Label();

public PojoMethodAdviceAdapter(int access , MethodVisitor mv , String methodName, String description, String className , int classFileVersion, boolean learning, int lineNumber, Map pendingMethod){
    super(Opcodes.ASM5 , mv, access, methodName, description);
    this.className = className;
    this.methodName = methodName;
    this.description = description;
}

public void visitCode() {
    super.visitCode(); 
    mv.visitLabel(startFinally);
}

protected void onMethodEnter(){
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, Constants.RootTracer, Constants.pojoMethodBegin, Constants.pojoMethodBeginDesc, false);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);
}

protected void onMethodExit(int opcode){
    if(opcode!=ATHROW) {
        onFinally(opcode);
    }
}

public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals){
    Label endFinally = new Label();
    mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, null);
    mv.visitLabel(endFinally);
    onFinally(ATHROW);
    mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
    mv.visitMaxs(maxStack+4, maxLocals);
}

private void onFinally(int opcode){
    if(opcode == ATHROW){
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
        mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, Constants.RootTracer, Constants.recordPOJOException, Constants.recordPOJOExceptionDesc, false);
    }
    mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(opcode);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, Constants.RootTracer, Constants.pojoMethodEnd, Constants.pojoMethodEndDesc, false);
}
```

}